# iOS -- Differences between production builds and local builds

Tags: ios, app-store

My app seems to behave differently in the app store than it does when I do builds from my laptop.

The differences show up *immediately* on app load.  Here are the two scenarios:

Local Build: Starting with the app deleted from my phone, I do a build from Xcode.  The splash screen shows up, it asks for my location, I accept, and my first page shows up, with my animations.

Then I take that exact code and submit it to the app store, where it gets approved.  (I've done this twice now, to make sure I wasn't accidentally uploading the wrong branch or something).

App Store Build: Starting with the app deleted from my phone, I download it from the app store, accept location perms, and my first page loads, without my animations.

Both are built against the production servers.

There just seem to be so few variables between these two contexts that I'm having a hard time figuring out how it could be a bug in my code that's doing this.  I figured there might be some differences in how apps that are archived for the app store are built, maybe performance strategies that affect animations?  Or might there be some other difference between a local build and an app store archive that could cause this?

Comment: how do you make the "animation" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build and run on your device using XCode, you are building using the "Run" scheme, whereas when you build your app for the App Store you use the "Profile" scheme. The Build Configuration for the Run scheme is called "Debug" whereas the build configuration for the Profile scheme is called "Release".

In order to achieve parity, you need to change the build configuration for the Run scheme to "Release". You do that in this way:

```
* Click on the app icon next to the play button on the top left in XCode
* Select "Edit Scheme".
* Click on "Run" in the left pane
* Change Build Configuration to "Release"
* Close
* Build and Run
```

In theory, your app should now run as it does when downloaded from the app store.